# CASE with variable and static response

Tags: sql, informix

I am trying to form a CASE statement that will generate a fixed response if the criteria is met or will respond with the value in the field. I am getting a "800: Corresponding data types must be compatible in CASE expression or DECODE function." error when executing the query. From my understanding it is caused when the response types do not match, a mismatch in the format.  However the response of `f.frequency` is a 9 digit integer if not null (so the type of `f.frequency` is INTEGER).

This works:

```
CASE
    WHEN f.frequency is null AND d.appid = 7 THEN '999000000'
    ELSE null
    END AS frequency,
```

Or this

```
CASE
    WHEN f.frequency is not null THEN f.frequency
    ELSE null
    END AS frequency,
```

but not when I combine them as in

```
CASE
    WHEN f.frequency is null AND d.appid = 7 THEN '999000000'
    WHEN f.frequency is not null THEN f.frequency
    ELSE null
    END AS frequency,
```

or like this

```
CASE
    WHEN f.frequency is null AND d.appid = 7 THEN '999000000'
    ELSE f.frequency
    END AS frequency,
```

Comment: The problem is I think that f.frequency and '999000000' has a diferent data type. Maybe f.frequency has more characters than '999000000'. Change the order of the case like: 
CASE
    WHEN f.frequency is not null THEN f.frequency
    WHEN f.frequency is null AND d.appid = 7 THEN '999000000'
    ELSE null
    END AS frequency,

Comment: In the first two examples, the only types are either the string or the integer value of frequency, plus NULL which can be of any necessary type.  Where you run into trouble is when you have two distinct types plus the null, which can't readily be resolved.  If you want a 9-digit integer, use the 9-digit integer notation without quotes.  If you want a 9-character string, you could cast the frequency to a string: `CAST(f.frequency AS CHAR(9))` for example.  This would also resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from the error is that '999000000' and f.frequency are different data types.

Casting '999000000' to whatever datatype your frequency column is should do the trick.

Also (at least in postgres) '999000000' is not an int so you may just want to remove the quotes